# How to turn on Dark Mode in Pages

Tags: macos, mojave, pages, settings, dark-mode

I just updated to Mojave, and I am really enjoying Dark mode. Today I opened Pages for the first time. When opening Pages I see a splash screen that says what is new with Pages and Dark mode is listed, but for some reason Pages is not showing in dark mode.

Anyone have this issue, and have been able to resolve it?

Comment: I just launched Pages and it was already in dark mode for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the issue. Turns out that my dark mode preferences switched back to Light mode. When I turned Dark Mode back on, Pages switch to Dark mode as well.

Looks like I have a different problem... My Dark Mode seems to be switching back to light mode from time to time.

I resolved this toggle issue here:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/337808/183752

Comment: Further, it appears the dark mode switches to light mode after when I log in after a restart or log off

Comment: Looks like you witnessed an epic battle of light between dark mode and flux!

Comment: Epic indeed! The Dark Side always comes out on top