# MacOS Dark Mode toggles back to Light Mode

Tags: macos, catalina, mojave, big-sur, dark-mode

I have an issue were when I log into MacOS Dark mode seems to be toggling back to light mode.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I resolved this issue. Turns out I have an app installed that changes the color temperature of my screen (flux). This app seems to be toggling Dark mode back to light mode because it detects its day time. I turned the App off and this solved the problem.

**Edit:**
Turns out the Flux option Color Effect --> OS X Dark Theme at sunset was the root cause. I toggled this off and now I am using flux and Dark mode!

Comment: Thanks for this, I was baffled as for why my Mojave was going light all the time. Glad to see it's not a bug in the OS. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for that! Happened to me only after the upgrade to Big Sur. Mentioning it here as I can't add the OS as another tag to the original question - no more than 5 tags ;)

Comment: @retrovertigo thanks for the comment. I removed the settings tag and added big sur. That tag will likely be more helpful then "settings"