# MacOS dark mode not working

Tags: macos, dark-mode

No matter how I try to change my Mac color to dark mode, it keeps changing to light.[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have an app installed that overrides this setting?: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337807/macos-dark-mode-toggles-back-to-light-mode?rq=1

Comment: I'm not sure, how to check?

Comment: Well, go through your apps and check whether one of them has that feature and see if its turned on. And maybe read the other question I linked.

Comment: I deleted all my recently download applications and restarted my computer but it still doesn't work

Comment: Please provide terminal output as text so we can cut and paste it to try to reproduce the issue